# Using aspectjtools.jar into Android project

Tags: android, aspectj

I've imported **aspectjtools.jar** in my Android project, but when I run the project (no matter if I use or not the .jar in the code), eclipse shows the following warning:

```
[2012-03-05 16:34:20 - AndroidExample] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-03-05 16:34:20 - AndroidExample] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.core.ClasspathContainerInitializer$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

After showing several times the same warning Eclipse stops working and I have to restart it.

I tried using Maven but it showed the same warning, and after 1 minute showing the warning, the project compiles but doesn't work fine.

Any idea to how solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You apparently need to modify your Eclipse  configuration so the weaving occurs between bytecode compilation and conversion to the Android .dex format. See [this article](http://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/).

Comment: But, I'm not trying to import the AspectJ library **aspectjrt.jar**, i followed the [http://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/]article and with this library the project works fine. the problem appears when i import **aspectjtools.jar** . Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, why do you need to import aspectjtools.jar into your project? What does it do differently to the AJDT method, as described in that article?